# How do you handle rename operations when calling IContextMenu?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I'm calling `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` with `CMF_CANRENAME` and I'm having problems handling the rename operation when calling `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand` on Windows XP.

I'm not a namespace extension and I'm not using DefView/IShellView but I am providing a site that implements `IServiceProvider`.

On newer versions of Windows I'm queried for a service that implements IFolderView2 and the shell calls [`IFolderView2::DoRename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775517(v=vs.85).aspx) and I can start the rename operation.

On Windows XP however it queries for the `SID_DefView` service but I cannot find any information about how I'm supposed to implement that service.

The interface it (SHELL32!CDefFolderMenu::_ProcessRename) is asking for is {985F64F0-D410-4E02-BE22-DA07F2B5C5E1} and I can see in the registry that this is the IID for `IDefViewFrame3` but it seems to be undocumented! [IDefViewFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762075(v=vs.85).aspx) on the other hand is documented but the only thing MSDN says is "Used only for its IUnknown functionality. It has no methods of its own.".

Is there a documented way to handle rename operations on XP in this situation?

I don't really want to fake a IDefViewFrame3 interface but the only other option I can think of is to see if it is the rename verb and just handle it myself after `TrackPopupMenu`.

Comment: Consider whether you really need to support XP.

Comment: If I am reading your question right, some other piece of code is asking your code to perform a rename operation, and you are internally using a shell context menu to perform the actual rename. Is that right? Are you asking how to implement `IDefViewFrame3` to receive that initial rename request?

Comment: For the actual rename, you don't need `TrackPopupMenu()`. You would simply `QueryContextMenu()` to fill an `HMENU` with menu items, then locate the `Rename` menu item and pass its ID to `InvokeCommand()`. Or just skip `QueryContextMenu()` and pass a hard-coded `"rename"` verb to `InvokeCommand()`.

Comment: BTW, MSDN is lying about `IDefViewFrame`, it actually defines 3 methods, as can be seen in `shlobj.h` - `GetWindowLV()`, `ReleaseWindowLV()`, and `GetShellFolder()`. None of those have anything to do with performing shell actions, though.  As for `IDefViewFrame3`, not only is it undocumented, but it is also not declared anywhere in the Win32 SDK headers, so it is likely a private interface that MS uses internally and does not want 3rd party developers to implement manually.

Comment: Which is further backed up by IID `{985F64F0-D410-4E02-BE22-DA07F2B5C5E1}` also being associated with [`IDefViewID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762074.aspx), which has the same "Used only for its IUnknown functionality" comment in its documentation, and is not declared as a distinct interface in any Win32 SDK header, it is just a `#define` alias for `IUnknown`.

Comment: @Remy If I pretend to implement IDefViewFrame3 then it does call me back on some method that does not exist in IDefViewFrame v1! It is the 5th method after IUnknown and that would be plausible for v3. These interfaces are clearly not used just for detection. I just feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree (even though it does seem to work) but I don't think the rename verb is documented either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDefViewFrame3 looks like this after IUnknown on Windows XP:

```
STDMETHOD(GetWindowLV)(THIS_ HWND*phwnd) PURE;
STDMETHOD(ShowHideListView)(THIS) PURE;
STDMETHOD(OnResizeListView)(THIS) PURE;
STDMETHOD(ReleaseWindowLV)(THIS) PURE;
STDMETHOD(DoRename)(THIS) PURE;
```

and `DoRename` is called by DefView inside `InvokeCommand` but since it is so obscure and undocumented it is unlikely that all 3rd-party namespace extensions handle it correctly so even if you implement IDefViewFrame3 you still have to check for the rename verb if `InvokeCommand` fails.