# Explorer-style ListView which contains custom list of files

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi, explorer

When in Files Explorer we use <kbd>F3</kbd> search feature, this generates a `ListView` which contains certain files (search results).

[image]

**Is it possible, and if so with which WinAPI widget using Visual C++, to have a similar files explorer ListView that contains a custom list of files (files might not be in the same directory, etc.)?**

i.e. a ListView which has all the native Explorer UI elements (small icons near the filename, right click opens a popup with actions to do on the files, etc.)

WinSpector says it's `DirectUIHWND`, but can we create one and pass an array of files to display in it?

To be more precise: I know how to display text items in a `SysListView32`, but how to display *files*, and have all the features available in Explorer (right click -> contextual menu for files, with Open, Open with, etc., F2 -> rename file, etc.) directly without having to re-code all these hundreds of features?

Comment: Create a list view control, and put whatever you like in it. `DirectUIHWND` is a private MS control that wraps the system list view control. You should use a system list view control. It's a little difficult to know what the question is here. You seem to be asking, "is it possible to display things in a list view". That is trivially answered in the affirmative.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidHeffernan. I know how to display text items in `SysListView32`, but my question is: how to display *files*, and have all the features available in Explorer (right click -> contextual menu for files, with Open, Open with, etc., F2 -> rename file, etc.) directly in a `ListView` without having to re-code all these hundreds of features.

Comment: That's a massively broad question. There are many examples just a websearch away that demonstrate how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer in Windows Vista and older uses the standard listview control, Window 7 and later by default uses a custom control that looks like a listview.

Before writing your own implementation you should try [`IExplorerBrowser`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17809/Host-Windows-Explorer-in-your-applications-using-t), specifically the [`FillFromObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761903(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

If you want to use a listview, the basics are:

- Use [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx) or `IExtractIcon` to get the system image list and the icon index for each file.
- Get a `IContextMenu` from `IShellFolder` or `SHCreateDefaultContextMenu` when you need to [display a context menu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823).
- [Handle drag & drop](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041206-00/?p=37133/).
- [Handle rename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40497455).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Anders. I don't necessarily want a `SysListView32`, I just would like to use the simplest method to have all the explorer-style features without having to re-code them. So it seems I should better use `IExplorerBrowser`? Do you think I'll be able to fill it with hundreds of thousands of files? (example: all JPG files of the hard drive that I've indexed before, etc.)

Comment: IExplorerBrowser uses the same custom control as Explorer, it is probably the same implementation internally so the performance should be the same as searching for all .jpg files in Explorer.

Comment: ...and in normal shell fashion, not everything is documented so IExplorerBrowser does not work correctly with fancy control panel items that take over the whole window IIRC.

Comment: Thanks! (what is the fancy control panel items case in your last comment? i don't see exactly which case wouldn't work)

Comment: In Explorer some control panel items take over the entire window, hiding the treeview and other items. I'm sure IExplorerBrowser can support it but all that stuff is undocumented.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't even know that. Thanks for the info! So feeding the `IExplorerBrowser` with files can be done directly with `FillFromObject`? If you have a code example, feel free to post it here, it will be useful for future reference.

Comment: Actually explorer, even today, uses SysListView32. In Windows 7 and later it is wrapped, but dig into the children and there's the SysListView32.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No? Not on my Windows 8 machine at least. The tree uses SysTreeView32 but there is no listview. It just goes .. -> SHELLDLL_DefView (Window created by IShellView/IShellFolder) -> DirectUIHWND (the file list) -> CtrlNotifySink -> ScrollBar. You can use a registry setting to get Windows 7 to act like Vista and use the listview but it is not used by default.